# Bib entry cannot be encoded in ansinew

Tags: biblatex, biber, urls

I'm compiling the following files which are enconded in Western-1252. Using biber to compile the bib

**example.tex**

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-noquoting, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish]{translator}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[firstinits=true, url=true, doi=false, style=alphabetic, sorting=nyt, maxnames=5]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{
    urlseen = {Última visita},
    urlfrom = {from},
    url = {url},
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\textsc{\bibstring{url}}:\space\url{#1}}
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}

Hola que tal \cite{Doe:2009:Online}

\end{document}
```

**example.bib**

```
@ONLINE{Doe:2009:Online,
author = {Doe, Ringo},
title = {This is a test entry of type {@ONLINE}},
month = jun,
year = {2009},
url = {http://www.test.org/doe/?a},
urldate = {2008},
}
```

If I include a ? or a % in the url I get the following error:

*The entry 'Doe:2009:Online' has characters which cannot be encoded in 'ansinew'. Recoding problematic characters into macros.*

Any idea why is that? the question mark exists in ansinew. How can I escape the code in the url?

---

**Edit:**

Another try using this, didn't work:

```
\usepackage[firstinits=true, url=true, doi=false, style=alphabetic, sorting=nyt, maxnames=5, bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
```

---

**Edit2:**

I have realized the problem is somewhere with the final pdflatex execution:

```
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 MAGNET. \OT1/cmr/m/it/10.95 Pro-ject Na-me\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 . 2004. \OT1/cmr/m/sc/10.95 Url\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 : [][]$\OT1/pcr/m/n/10.95 http :$
[28]
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$

@STRING{NAME = "ProjectShort"}
@STRING{NAME_LONG = "{ProjectLong}"}

@MISC{MAGNET:PROJECT,
 author = {{NAME}},
title = NAME_LONG,
subtitle = {{FP6-IST-1234}},
year = "2004",
url = {http://www.proect.org},
urldate = {2008},
}
```

Comment: Do you *really* need `ansinew`? Every good editor is capable of dealing with UTF-8.

Comment: @egreg It is the final stage of my PhD and I'm not changing the character encoding of all the files and have the risk on some packages not supporting it. I'm thinking on just removing the url from this entries, but I prefer to know how to solve it.

Comment: I get the warning but despite that biber seems to put an unencoded ? into the generated bbl file and it all seems to work, so just ignoring the warning seems to be a possibility (but if it wasn't the final stage of your phd, using utf8 or latin1 instead of ansinew would be better) (but i get the warning withlatin1 as well on this MWE:-)

Comment: The question mark is an ASCII character and is encoded the same way in `ansinew`, `latin`, `utf8` and many other encodings.

Comment: I do not get the warning with biber 1.8, biblatex 2013/11/25 2.8a, babel 2014/03/24 3.9k, spanish.ldf 2014/04/24 v5.0n.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek have just updated everything (a big risk right now) and it is not working. I will be removing the urls.

Comment: I get the warning with biber 1.9. The percent sign works OK by using `\%`. I tried to diagnose the problem by searching the biber 1.9 source code (written in Perl) for a substring of the warning. I found the following piece of code in `lib/Biber/Output/bbl.pm` which triggers the warning, if true: `encode($outenc, NFC($entry_string)) =~ /\?/`. The test is only done if non-UTF-8 output is needed. To me it looks like the code uses a `?` in the output of `encode()` as a sign of failed character set conversion. I think a warning follows when a `?` is already present in the input. Bug?

Comment: Addition to my previous comment: there have been no changes to `lib/Biber/Output/bbl.pm` in [biber's repository](https://github.com/plk/biber) after biber 1.9.

Comment: I solved the problem!!!! It was a _ in one refence that I didn't escape. Over almost 200 reference it was quite hard to find why it didn't work. Now the warnings are still there but they are correclty printed THANKS EVERYBODY!!!

Comment: I reported an "Issue" on biber's GitHub page about the question mark warning.

Comment: The author of biber was quick to [fix](https://github.com/plk/biber/commit/86cae08db934cda598b111febdebf004d1329396) the warning issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem with biber that was fixed (see comment above).